# Format a button in form_tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<% if is_admin? %>
  <%= form_tag(controller: "generalizacoes", action: "destroy_all", method: :post) do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :item_id, @item.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :genero_id, genero.id %>
    <%= submit_tag 'x'%>
  <% end -%>
<% end %>
```

Ugly as hell

[image: It looks like this:]

I want it to be something like

Guerra x (little remove-glyphicon from twitter bootstrap)

Is it possible? What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
<%= submit_tag('x', class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm') %>
```

There are [other bootstrap options for buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons) though.

You could also look at [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) which seems a good fit for what you're doing:

```
<%= button_to("X", { controller: "generalizacoes", action: "destroy_all" },
    { params: { item_id: @item.id, genero_id: genero.id },
      class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm' %>
```

You might want a `data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }` in there too if it's a destructive action.

Comment: actually it doesn't changed much... It still a giant bar, just more stylized. And I can't insert a glyphicon in it like here: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="remove-rel-item-genero">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</button>`

Answer (score 1):

This won't be a direct answer (not bootstrap), but should give you information on how to fix the issue

---

**CSS**

You can style your input / submit buttons anyway you want - using `css`.

As you can see from my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvm62gtm/):

```
.new_button {
    background-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: background, 0.2s;
}

.new_button:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

<form action="#">
   <input type="submit" value="Test" class="new_button">
</form>
```

Although `bootstrap` will include its own array of classes & styles, you have to remember that if you want to give your buttons a particular "style", you'll be able to define & invoke the various CSS classes / styles which you define.

This is mentioned in the answer by `Shadwell` - you can style the button individually by calling a class on it, or, alternatively, you can rely on the `form` styling inside Bootstrap itself:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
.your_class { 
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#app/views/controller/your_view.html.erb
<%= form_tag(controller: "generalizacoes", action: "destroy_all", method: :post) do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :item_id, @item.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :genero_id, genero.id %>
    <%= submit_tag 'x', class: "your_class" %>
<% end -%>
```

---

**Bootstrap**

I must admit, I've never used Bootstrap for CSS before.

You'll be able to build on what I've given above, by using the `bootstrap` CSS styles for [forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) & [buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons). You can do that this way:

```
<%= form_tag(controller: "generalizacoes", action: "destroy_all", method: :post) do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :item_id, @item.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :genero_id, genero.id %>
    <%= submit_tag 'x', class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, but I still have a problem, the still button stay above the text, I mean, the width of it is the same size as my column, what should I do to it stays right after the text?